# Syntax highlight strings in compilation-mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, compile-mode

Is it possible to activate syntax highlighting for strings in compilation mode?

Sometimes the compilation error output of some C++ linter is quite unreadable. Lengthy types and function definitions are printed with some small explanation in between. For example:

> foo.cpp:147:60: info 1764: parameter 'foo' of type '`NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &' of function 'NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CBar::setAs(const unsigned int, const NamespaceX::NamespaceY::CFoobar &, const NamespaceX::NamespaceZ::Cbarbaz &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, const NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &)' of type '_Bool (unsigned int, const NamespaceX::NamespaceY::CNamespaceY &, const NamespaceX::NamespaceZ::Cbarbaz &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, const NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &)' could be reference to const

If those '' strings would be highlighted with `font-lock-string-face`, then the relevant information could be spotted more easily.

> foo.cpp:147:60: info 1764: parameter '`foo`' of type '`NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &`' of function '`NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CBar::setAs(const unsigned int, const NamespaceX::NamespaceY::CFoobar &, const NamespaceX::NamespaceZ::Cbarbaz &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, const NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &)`' of type '`_Bool (unsigned int, const NamespaceX::NamespaceY::CNamespaceY &, const NamespaceX::NamespaceZ::Cbarbaz &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, const NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &, NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::CFoo &)`' could be reference to const

Is there a way to activate that? Could it probably be done by changing the syntax-table used by compilation mode (if that is used)?

Or is there a minor mode available that I could activate?

Comment: You may wish to add a custom regexp to the `compilation-error-regexp-alist`; or, parse the buffer again when it finishes; or, add a second parsing after or before `compilation-parse-errors`.